# phpexcel changes permissions of loaded file

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, file-permissions

I am trying to have an online application that consistently adds data to an excel sheet as more people apply. I have the basics of the form working, but I'm running into the issue that the applications.xlsx file I've made on the server to hold the data keeps changing permissions to be read only, so I cannot go into the sheet and edit columns or widths or anything that I need to be able to change while setting it up. And I want to be able to edit it after I have it fully running incase I need to change a column later on or someone inputs some data incorrectly, etc. My code is below, minus all the data I'm collecting.

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel */
echo __FILE__;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$excelFile = 'private_files/Applications.xlsx';

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excelFile);
$objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['time']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $_POST['fname']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $_POST['pname']);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($excelFile);
```

I've tried to just alter the permissions via windows explorer, but whenever a new entry is written the permissions are changed, and I've tried looking through other posts and google but I can't find a way to change the permissions through phpexcel in the first place so I don't know what's going on.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 'fraid not - PHPExcel ___reads___ files and/or ___writes___ files: it does absolutely nothing to change any permissions ever

Comment: However, writing a file is treated as creating a new file, even if an existing file of the same name exists